# I want disable cache for Magento 2.15 cms page backend

Tags: magento2

```
I need to update the CMS page often hence I want to disable the cache for that particular page. I have tried using xml in cms page "Layout Update XML" with the following code 
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>
    </head>
```

Still i could not disable cache.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to update the CMS page often hence I want to disable the cache for that particular page. I have tried using xml in cms page "Layout Update XML" with the following code.

```
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Page" name="cms_page" cacheable="false"/>
```

Comment: will it work if template called from cms? I need to use cacheable false there

Comment: <block class="block_class" name="test_file" template="module_name::file_path/file_name.phtml" cacheable="false"/>

Comment: yes, like this if we use, it works, but we need to do from cms.

Comment: I am loading template from cms block

Comment: It don't work in cms block. In which page you want to add template file.